# Let $G$ be a group. Let $N\unlhd G$ with $G/N$ being cyclic. Let $H\leq G$. Show that $HN\unlhd G$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Let $N\unlhd G$ with $G/N$ being cyclic. Let $H\leq G$. Show that $HN\unlhd G$.

I cannot figure out how to use the fact that $G/N$ is cyclic in this proof. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $G/N$ is abelian, $HN/N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$. By the correspondence between subgroups of $G/N$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ (which preserves normality), this implies that $HN$ is normal in $G$

Comment: Oh my gosh! I was going crazy writing an explicit proof, thanks for this!

Comment: Ah thanks! Couldn't see to use the Correspondence Theorem; that makes a lot of sense.